# Is striping certain information from a C++ binary safe?

Tags: c++, debug-symbols

I am brand new to C++, trying to create a program to read pixels on the screen on Linux.

I currently compile the project without any optimization flag, as I am unsure what it does to the program, but that would be another question, here's mine:

**Is striping certain information from a C++ binary safe?**

I found a possibly helpful [manual page of `strip`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strip) program.

As I don't *really* know what striping means in this context, I am unsure if it is as simple as striping all of it with:

> ```
> -s --strip-all    Remove all symbol and relocation information
> ```

But, of course, I'd want the program to work flawlessly then, so does it interfere anyhow with program's execution?

---

As for my motivation for striping: I want to know if it's safe, and as I said already, I repeat:

> I don't *really* know what striping means in this context.

I thought the answerer could have also covered this. For me to decide.

Comment: For "release" builds use the `-O2` optimization flag, it's safe (unless you have *undefined behavior* in your code). And its also safe to strip your executable.

Comment: Why do you want to strip your executable? In many cases, it is not worth the effort. I would recommend compiling with `g++ -Wall -g -O2` and not strip your executable. It is more than 20 years that I never stripped the executables I am obtaining by compiling source code.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I am just too much curious as for my options in the whole programming process maybe :)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch it can result much smaller binaries - which in some cases can be very useful.  It can also make reverse engineering the binary a little harder.

Comment: Also, disk space is cheap. So I don't strip anymore. And I don't care about reverse engineering: all the code I am writing is free software, and I am happy when someone is looking into my source code. Sadly, that does not happen often enough. Of course, if you are paid to write proprietary software, you should somehow `strip` it (but that is more a pain in the ass than not doing it). Still, the motivation for stripping is missing in the question

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch sure there is in the comments - curiosity.  And just because you don't care about reverse engineering, and you only write free code, and you like when people look at your stuff, doesn't mean that that's the case for anyone else.  I would argue that in fact you are the exception.

Comment: @UKMonkey: the OP is *learning* C++. I don't think that his executable is valuable to anyone but him. So in his shoes I would not bother a second about stripping. That could become (later) a concern, once he is fluent in C++ (and becoming fluent in C++ takes years of practice)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Since I would actually like others to be able to easily debug my program, I do open-source, as far as I understand it, you do it likewise. I don't see a point of debugging the binary directly, though. Since anyone will be able to look at the code, why would they? Again, I ask out of curiosity.

Comment: Then, it is better to not strip your binary. Because it would be easier for others (and for you) to debug potential `core` dumps. Analyzing a `core` from a stripped binary is more painful than analyzing a `core` from a non-stripped executable.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thank you for valuable information!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Symbols are used for debugging.

Your application would continue to work with out issues if you strip them; but you may find it harder to debug if there's a problem.

Relocation information is used for dynamic library loading and for address space layout randomisation (thank you @interjay); and from the [strip documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/strip.html)

> --remove-relocations=sectionpattern
>
> ... Note that using this option inappropriately may make the output file unusable. ...

Comment: Isn't relocation information needed for dynamic library loading and for ASLR?

Comment: @interjay yes ... it's a monday morning ... what can I say  ;)